# Is it possible to write code locally and build it in docker image using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I have been playing around with the Docker extension for VSC and reading the documentation. So far what I have achieved is attaching to a docker container and modifying code inside that is later built.

The way I have it now I have two options:

a) Build the container, attach to it, and edit and build there, but being careful not to exit it or else all progress will be lost.
b) Edit it locally and build the image every time and run the container. With this option I have to compile the whole project every time.

What I would like to do, however, is to be able to write code locally and when I want to build it "copy" it inside a container, the build environment where all the dependencies are, so that if I have already compiled it before throughout the day only the new changes have to be compiled.

Do you know if it's possible to get something like this working, either with VSC or another tool? Thanks for your help

Comment: What kind of code are you writing? Is this .NET Core or something else? My first instinct is to point you at https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/ By using a multistage build, you can build all of the code within a throw away container and not have any dependency on VSC.

Comment: It's C++ and I have all the dependencies in a docker image